# Flash Player 11.2 Video Events addEventListener

Tags: actionscript-3, video, flash

Has anyone been able to get an addEventListener working with Flash Player 11.2?
I always get this error:

> Scene 1, Layer 'actions', Frame 1, Line 104   1119: Access of possibly
>   undefined property COMPLETE through a reference with static type
>   Class.

If I switch my flash player to output to 
here is my code:

```
 import flash.events.Event;
 import fl.video.VideoEvent;
 import fl.video.*;

 myVideo.source ="videoName.flv";
 myVideo.play();
 myVideo.addEventListener(VideoEvent.COMPLETE, vidComplete)

 function vidComplete(event:VideoEvent) {
      trace("done");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the AS3 compiler for Flash Player 11 in Flash CS6 seems to ignore the import statements for fl.video.*;

Source: http://forums.adobe.com/message/4699000

This person's solution implies that specifying the entire class package inline in the code as follows should alleviate the issue:

```
myVideo.source ="videoName.flv";
myVideo.play();
myVideo.addEventListener(fl.video.VideoEvent.COMPLETE, vidComplete)

function vidComplete(event:fl.video.VideoEvent) {
    trace("done");
}
```